# Erro de agregação somente no postgresql 9.4

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou tendo o seguinte erro quando utilizo o banco de dados postgresql em produção (versão 9.46), em desenvolvimento não aparece o erro (9.6).
PG::GroupingError: ERRO:  coluna "setores.nome" deve aparecer na cláusula GROUP BY ou ser utilizada em uma função de agregação.
segue a query sql:

```
    SELECT materiais.id material_id, insumos.nome material_nome, 
    apresentacoes.id apresentacao_id, apresentacoes.apresentacao 
    apresentacao_apresentacao, estoques.setor_id, estoques.setor_nome, 
    estoques.total total, estoques.valor_total valor_total FROM materiais
    INNER JOIN insumos ON insumos.id = materiais.insumo_id
    LEFT JOIN apresentacoes ON apresentacoes.material_id = materiais.id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT setores.nome setor_nome, 
                estoques.setor_id setor_id, 
                estoques.material_id, 
                estoques.apresentacao_id, 
                SUM(lotes.quantidade) total, 
                SUM(lotes.quantidade*lotes.valor_unitario_cents) valor_total
        FROM estoques 
        INNER JOIN setores ON setores.id = estoques.setor_id 
        INNER JOIN lotes ON lotes.estoque_id = estoques.id
        GROUP BY (setores.nome, 
                 estoques.setor_id, 
                 estoques.material_id,
                 estoques.apresentacao_id)
    ) 
    estoques ON estoques.material_id = materiais.id AND apresentacoes.id = 
    estoques.apresentacao_id 
    where materiais.setor_type = 'Farmacia' 
    ORDER BY insumos.nome DESC, apresentacoes.id
```

Obs: Já tentei usar uma função de agregação no select ficando: array_agg(setores.nome))[1] setor_nome. Porém o erro vai para a próxima coluna do select, fazendo com que eu agregasse todos as colunas. Alguém tem uma outra solução sem ser tão gambiarra? e.e

Comment: Você tem uma tabela `estoques` e também está atribuindo o apelido `estoques` a seu sub-select, já tentou atribuir um apelido diferente?

Comment: Note que foi introduzido na versão 9.6: "Ignore GROUP BY columns that are functionally dependent on other columns".

Comment: Mudei no nome do alias para estoques_total e o erro persiste. Talvez seja a versão do postegres mesmo, caso n surja outra opção irei tentar atualizar a versão do banco de produção.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estranho este erro, o comando SQL parece correto. Tente colocar o Sub Select em um `WITH`:

```sql
WITH query_estoques AS 
(
   SELECT setores.nome setor_nome, 
          estoques.setor_id setor_id, 
          estoques.material_id, 
          estoques.apresentacao_id, 
          SUM(lotes.quantidade) total, 
          SUM(lotes.quantidade*lotes.valor_unitario_cents) valor_total
   FROM estoques 
   INNER JOIN setores ON setores.id = estoques.setor_id 
   INNER JOIN lotes ON lotes.estoque_id = estoques.id
   GROUP BY (setores.nome, 
           estoques.setor_id, 
           estoques.material_id,
           estoques.apresentacao_id)
)

 SELECT materiais.id material_id, insumos.nome material_nome, 
    apresentacoes.id apresentacao_id, apresentacoes.apresentacao 
    apresentacao_apresentacao, query_estoques.setor_id, query_estoques.setor_nome, 
    query_estoques.total total, query_estoques.valor_total valor_total FROM materiais
 INNER JOIN insumos ON insumos.id = materiais.insumo_id
 LEFT JOIN apresentacoes ON apresentacoes.material_id = materiais.id
 LEFT JOIN query_estoques ON query_estoques.material_id = materiais.id AND apresentacoes.id = query_estoques.apresentacao_id 
 where materiais.setor_type = 'Farmacia' 
 ORDER BY insumos.nome DESC, apresentacoes.id
```

Ou tente usar o número correspondente a ordem das colunas no `GROUP BY` ao invés de usar os nomes:

```sql
SELECT setores.nome setor_nome, 
          estoques.setor_id setor_id, 
          estoques.material_id, 
          estoques.apresentacao_id, 
          SUM(lotes.quantidade) total, 
          SUM(lotes.quantidade*lotes.valor_unitario_cents) valor_total
   FROM estoques 
   INNER JOIN setores ON setores.id = estoques.setor_id 
   INNER JOIN lotes ON lotes.estoque_id = estoques.id
   GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Comment: Usando o número correspondente a ordem das colunas resolveu o problema, muito obrigado :D.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se é isto:

```
SELECT  materiais.id material_id, insumos.nome material_nome, 
            apresentacoes.id apresentacao_id, apresentacoes.apresentacao 
            apresentacao_apresentacao, estoques_total.setor_id, estoques_total.setor_nome, 
            estoques_total.total total, estoques_total.valor_total valor_total 
FROM materiais INNER JOIN insumos ON insumos.id = materiais.insumo_id
    LEFT JOIN apresentacoes ON apresentacoes.material_id = materiais.id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT  setores.nome setor_nome, 
                estoques.setor_id setor_id, 
                estoques.material_id, 
                estoques.apresentacao_id, 
                SUM(lotes.quantidade) total, 
                SUM(lotes.quantidade*lotes.valor_unitario_cents) valor_total
        FROM estoques 
        INNER JOIN setores ON setores.id = estoques.setor_id 
        INNER JOIN lotes ON lotes.estoque_id = estoques.id
        GROUP BY setores.nome, 
                 estoques.setor_id, 
                 estoques.material_id,
                 estoques.apresentacao_id
    ) AS estoques_total ON estoques_total.material_id = materiais.id AND apresentacoes.id = estoques_total.apresentacao_id 
WHERE materiais.setor_type = 'Farmacia' 
ORDER BY insumos.nome DESC, apresentacoes.id;`insira o código aqui`
```